# Error in Building a nearby places app using Androidx / Android Studio 3.5.3

Tags: android, google-maps, androidx, google-nearby

when I create the app I receive the following error in the Logcat:

```
2020-01-27 16:45:34.247 20798-20798/com.example.mtcloseby E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mtcloseby, PID: 20798
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mtcloseby.MapsActivity.nearByPlace(MapsActivity.java:111)
        at com.example.mtcloseby.MapsActivity.access$000(MapsActivity.java:40)
        at com.example.mtcloseby.MapsActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MapsActivity.java:89)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:243)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:127)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6313)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24933)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6724)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: thank you so much evan I have managed to fix it, the problem was I was using SupportMapFragment and it should be MapFragment

Comment: Glad to hear! Please consider posting your own answer to your question for the community's sake. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it, the problem was I was using SupportMapFragment and it should be MapFragment